# How would I use Maven to install the JCE Unlimited Strength Policy files?

Tags: java, maven-2, jce

Some code I have requires the JCE unlimited Strength Policy Files.  I'd like to add this dependency into the Maven Pom file so the other developers on my team don't have to individually each apply this to their systems.

I realize that the systems this is eventually deployed to will need to have the JCE files manually installed. This is a development solution only.

I was thinking that we would add the policy files to our repository and maven would be able to handle installation, but I am surprised that I can't find anyone else doing this (and blogging about it.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maybe try this:

- Bundle (`zip`?) the JCE unlimited strength policy files.
- Install them to your corporate repository as a `zip` dependency.
- Use the [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) goal to unpack the created dependency to `${java.home}/jre/lib/security` as part of your build, e.g. during `initialize` (see [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)).

Answer (score 15):

I've found that answer, when googling for Maven dependencies for policy JARs and realized that it's JRE installation specific, thus fixing this as part of Maven build will work only for developers and only when you have rights to /jre/lib/security folder. For me the following code hack works much better (invoke this as one of the very first things your application does):

```
    try {
        Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bart , This ans saved my time.

Comment: Hi Bart, with update to java1.8 this solution stopped working. Do you know similar trick for Java1.8 as well ?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Java 1.8.0_25 on OSX and it still works.

Comment: That is because javax.crypto.JceSecurity.isRestricted became final
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149417

Comment: @shashaDenovo There is a new solution from Andrey Karayvansky for Java 1.8 in this thread

Answer (score 11):

Java 8 security hack

```
    // hack for JCE Unlimited Strength
    Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, false);
```

Comment: I'm using `java 1.8.0_102`. It doesn't work for me :(